# Enlarge video controls of html5 video

Tags: html, video

I'm looking if there is  a way to enlarge the video controls of an html5 video player.

now your thinking why do he want to enlarge those controls, that's easy I need mobile support so i like some bigger controls

I tryed to use css like so:

```
video controls{
height: 50px;
}
```

This is  not working because its not an element

Comment: If the device supports html5 video, it should have its own, appropriately-sized controls.

Comment: Testing on nexus4 and its show the same controls as on the pc, and there are really small

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On most devices, the internet browser should make an appropriately sized video box with controls. However, it is possible to customize the controls. This article does a good job explaining how: http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5-video-controls-with-jquery/

You can do some with just CSS, but for most significant changes, you'll want to use JavaScript also.